# How to block incoming LAN traffic with ip route (XP)

Tags: windows-xp, networking

Is there a way to block all incoming LAN traffic to my box with the native ip route command. Possibly redirect traffic to a gateway that doesn't exist?

If not possible with ip route perhaps something else that is built in to the OS (Besides the firewall)

OS is XP.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to be able to block all incoming traffic, not use a firewall for this purpose but also want to be able to unblock all outgoing traffic? If this is what you want to do, short of writing your own firewall software I doubt there will any other option - apart from removing the ethernet cable! You will need to allow all established ip connections in which is easily done by any basic firewall package.